# GRUB rescue won't go away!

Tags: windows-7

As you can guess from the title I am a complete noob and stupidly to the dismay of all of you, I deleted the Ubuntu partition deleting GRUB and Ubuntu. So when I tried to install Windows 7, it said that it was an unknown filesystem.

I am also trying to dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Comment: Unknown filesystem as the Ubuntu partition uses EXT4. What you have to do is to delete the partitions and create new partitions in the Windows 7 installation menu. (Do not click upgrade, click custom). Windows will then format it in NTFS partition.

Comment: make an ntfs partition and install windows on it.

Answer (score 0):

Unknown filesystem as the Ubuntu partition uses EXT4. What you have to do is to delete the partitions and create new partitions in the Windows 7 installation menu. (Do not click upgrade, click custom). Windows will then format it in NTFS partition.

**EDIT**

As mentioned recently in the comments, he wants to dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu. You can do that easily by installing Windows first in one partition with a space in the hard disk (about 250GB for a 500GB harddisk). Install Windows 7 on the NTFS partition first.

Next, after the Windows installation, boot Ubuntu from a Live USB and start the installation. The Ubuntu installation will prompt you and ask if you want to dual-boot Ubuntu alongside with Windows, select that. Let the installation complete. Make sure you install Ubuntu in an internal hard drive.

GRUB will automatically be installed and configured.

Comment: You have to understand that I want to split my hard drive in half so half is for Ubuntu and half is for Windows 7

Comment: Oh, that is called dual-booting. I will edit the answer to provide a better solution. You should improve on your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have deleted the ubuntu partition from windows 7 and your grub got messed up.I have had the same problem too.If there was windows 7,it is still there in the hard disk but can't find the proper form of grub.
So you've to reinstall ubuntu to get back grub as well as windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

First, Make Sure all Linux Partitions are Deleted and does not Exist

Now Boot up **Windows 7 DVD**, Select Your Language and Proceed, and Then Press  **<kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>F10</kbd>**  And a Command Prompt will appear Then Type in the Following line:

**`bootsec.exe /FixMbr`**

It Will Respond with :

> **The Operation Completed Succesfully**

Now Reboot and see if Windows 7 Boots up, if the Problem Persists, Reboot into CD and Open Command Prompt as Above (**<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>**) and Type the Following And Press Enter After Each Line:

**`bootrec.exe /FixBoot`**
**`bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd`**

It Will respond with the same message after Each Line:

> **The Operation  Completed Succefully**

Reboot and see if the Problem Persists, If it does, then Boot Again the Windows 7 DVD and Open up Command Prompt and Type:

**`DiskPart`**

Don't Worry it won't Respond with anything, Now Type:

**`List Disk`**

Now it Will Lists all the Disks you have, You Should choose the Disk that contain the Windows 7, it;s Most Likely **Disk 0**, So Type:

**`Select Disk 0`**

Replace 0 With your Disk Number if it's not 0 and Then Type:

**`List Partition`**

Now it will list all your Partitions, It's Most likely to Be **Partition 1**, Then Type:

**`Select Partition 1`**

Also Replace 1 with the Number of your Partition if it's Not 1

Now Simply Type:

**`Active`**

And It Will respond with:

> **DiskPart marked the current partition as active**

Now Reboot And it Should Boot, Otherwise i can't Fix the Problem for you

After that you should be able to Access Windows 7 and Copy your Files, And then you can Insert Ubuntu Installation Disk and Install it.

Also, If you decide to Keep Windows 7 as your OS and Your Don't want to install Any other OS, and you want to Expand the Primary Partition to the Full size of the HDD, Delete all the Other Partitions so they are **Unallocated Space**, Open up Command Prompt in Windows 7 and Run **DiskPart** and Select Disk and Then Partition and Type:

**`Expand`**

and The Current Partition will take all the Avaliable HDD Spcae and will respond:

> **Operation Completed Successfully**

However, This Only Works if the Unallocated space is After the Partition.

***Sorry for the Long Answer.***

Comment: Should i make this a Wiki Post? At First didn't Realize that i wrote all that xd